# CSS > Font-awesome multi star rating

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am using this example to provide rating in my page for multi-sections

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgLomj

My problem is that when I set the first group of start it affects other groups; I just want to know how to made each one works independently.

```
<input type="radio" id="star5" name="rating" value="5" checked/>
<label class = "full" for="star5" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
```

But currently when I set each input to "checked" it affects other groups of stars.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please include the relevant code to reproduce your problem in your question, linking to an external demo is a *bonus*, but not required. Whereas posting the relevant, "*[MCVE]*" code in your question *is* a requirement; and the absence of such is grounds for closing a question as "off-topic."

Comment: Have a look at this. https://github.com/dreyescat/bootstrap-rating

Comment: @CannotFindSymbol I dont want to use javascript , i need it to be css only

Comment: @DavidThomas; I really did not know where to start as I can't find the error in my code

Comment: change you id with class

Comment: @SyedArifIqbal, Thanks but it did not worked , I change all inputs id to unique one on each group but still did not work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is your input name is same for all both group. change all input name for all group set.

**the HTML**

```
<h1>Pure CSS Star Rating Widget 1</h1>
<fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5a" name="ratinga" value="5" checked/><label class = "full" for="star5a" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4halfa" name="ratinga" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4halfa" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4a" name="ratinga" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4a" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3halfa" name="ratinga" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3halfa" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3a" name="ratinga" value="3" /><label class = "full" for="star3a" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2halfa" name="ratinga" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2halfa" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2a" name="ratinga" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2a" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1halfa" name="ratinga" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1halfa" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1a" name="ratinga" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1a" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="starhalfa" name="ratinga" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalfa" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>

<div> <br><br><br><div>
<h1>Pure CSS Star Rating Widget 2</h1>
<fieldset class="rating">
    <input type="radio" id="star5b" name="ratings" value="5" /><label class = "full" for="star5b" title="Awesome - 5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4halfb" name="ratings" value="4 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star4halfb" title="Pretty good - 4.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star4b" name="ratings" value="4" /><label class = "full" for="star4b" title="Pretty good - 4 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3halfb" name="ratings" value="3 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star3halfb" title="Meh - 3.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star3b" name="ratings" value="3" checked/><label class = "full" for="star3b" title="Meh - 3 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2halfb" name="ratings" value="2 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star2halfb" title="Kinda bad - 2.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star2b" name="ratings" value="2" /><label class = "full" for="star2b" title="Kinda bad - 2 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1halfb" name="ratings" value="1 and a half" /><label class="half" for="star1halfb" title="Meh - 1.5 stars"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="star1b" name="ratings" value="1" /><label class = "full" for="star1b" title="Sucks big time - 1 star"></label>
    <input type="radio" id="starhalfb" name="ratings" value="half" /><label class="half" for="starhalfb" title="Sucks big time - 0.5 stars"></label>
</fieldset>
```

**the CSS**

```
@import url(//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css);

fieldset, label { margin: 0; padding: 0; }
body{ margin: 20px; }
h1 { font-size: 1.5em; margin: 10px; }

/****** Style Star Rating Widget *****/

.rating { 
  border: none;
  float: left;
}

.rating > input { display: none; } 
.rating > label:before { 
  margin: 5px;
  font-size: 1.25em;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  display: inline-block;
  content: "\f005";
}

.rating > .half:before { 
  content: "\f089";
  position: absolute;
}

.rating > label { 
  color: #ddd; 
 float: right; 
}

/***** CSS Magic to Highlight Stars on Hover *****/

.rating > input:checked ~ label, /* show gold star when clicked */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover, /* hover current star */
.rating:not(:checked) > label:hover ~ label { color: #FFD700;  } /* hover previous stars in list */

.rating > input:checked + label:hover, /* hover current star when changing rating */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover,
.rating > label:hover ~ input:checked ~ label, /* lighten current selection */
.rating > input:checked ~ label:hover ~ label { color: #FFED85;  }
```

Comment: did you try changing and seeing the output?

Comment: Sorry I can not understand your last comment, would you please provide me with example?

Comment: @Reddy please think and try yourself before thumb down for any answer

Comment: @SyedArifIqbal I am trying it for past 30 minutes as  I knew that was one of the problem, that still didnt resolve the issue. So I asked you if you had tried it yet.

Comment: i tried and it's working but now it's time to check by you.

Comment: @SyedArifIqbal can you add a working code snippet to prove your answer instead of simply dumping large code..

Comment: @SyedArifIqbal when tested with your html it is working fine, But when I use the codepen provided by the OP and change names there I doesnt work.. Anyways your answer works now for me.. +1

Comment: please check working example on this url i post above

Comment: @SyedArifIqbal I accepted that the answer is right :)